# Combining Multiple MPG Files

Tags: bash, shell, video, ffmpeg

I have an interesting problem...

I have created multiple mpg files (5 total) using FFMPEG. Once the files are done the are 30 seconds in length, I did this purposefully.

My Problem is, when I cat *.mpg >> final.mpg it creates the final.mpg but chops off a totally of 18 seconds. Its approximately 3.2 seconds of each mpg.

Does anyone know a better way to combine these files using bash without loosing those extra seconds?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the individual video chunks still playable in the combined version? Or is one or more of them skipped? If the time's changing in the "full" video, then either one of more component videos is being skipped, or there's differences between the videos causing some to be played faster than the others, which "loses" time.

Comment: Yea, they all play just fine in the "Final" output, just shorter by 3.2 seconds and yes, they are all identical. I setup a bash script that runs FFMPEG through a group of images which gets converted into MPGS.

Answer (score 1):

Using [MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/),

```
mencoder -oac copy -ovc copy -of mpeg -o final.mpg input1.mpg input2.mpg input3.mpg ...
```

However, given the workflow that you stated… wouldn't it be easier to just pass all the images to FFmpeg at once?

Comment: That did not worked, when i used a MPG file to MPG file conversion. Where the file was 50 frames per second 720P. Either the video and audio gets broken. Never getting perfect.